# allow other networks to connect to my computer through the internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, network-protocols

I am trying to create a virtual machine with virtualBox which can be accessed from other networks. I explain myself more; I have an application in my virtual machine and I want that from another team that is connected to another network can access this application and visualize it. I tried to configure a NAT, BRIDGE and HOST-ONLY network but I can not get other networks to connect, I also tried the port forwarding and manage my modem to open ports and create a public ip, but i dont know much of that, can you really achieve that kind of functionality with a virtual machine?

I can say that when I set up my virtual machine to work with a NAT network I could only connect through ssh through a local dirrecion which I do not understand, according to the descriptions a NAT network should be used to allow other networks to connect to my computer or virtual machine through the internet.

Comment: If the other network is not in your own network, then you are going to need a VPN too.

Answer (score 0):

If the network adapter of the virtual machine is defined as Bridged, it will
behave just like another physical machine on the network, including having
an IP address.

To connect to your VM across the Internet, you need to:

- Give the VM a static IP address on the network.
  Consult the manual of your router to see how to narrow the DHCP range of addresses
  to avoid any conflict.
- Define the ports your application will need.
- Create in the router a port-forwarding mapping of these ports to the IP address
  of the VM.
  Consult the manual of the router, and if in doubt consult the website
  [Port Foward](https://portforward.com/) for your router model.
- Give your router an Internet name via a free DNS service such as
  [no-ip.com](http://freeddns.noip.com).
  If your ISP changes your Internet IP address on every boot of the router,
  remember to update it when it happens. Some routers can do that automatically,
  so check yours.

When this is done, you may refer to the VM by the given DNS name across the
Internet. But don't try to check it from withing your own network,
since most consumer routers will not allow a loopback connection
(meaning computer -> Internet -> same computer).